# How to make geometry retain its size regardless of the size of the renderer - Plane changes size depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image]

I'm adding a codepen of the issue. And a GIF showing exactly what I'm confused by.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/carelesscourage/pen/bGMWjNg

**My expectation**

I want the plane to be the same size regardless of screen size.

```
//WebGl renderer
function useWebGl(root = document.body) {
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true })
  renderer.setClearColor( 0x009900, 1 )
  renderWindow(renderer)
  root.appendChild( renderer.domElement )
  onResize(() => renderWindow(renderer))
  return { WebGl: renderer }
}

function renderWindow(renderer) {
  const { height, width } = windowDimensions()
  renderer.setSize( width / 2, height / 2 )
}


//ThreeJS Engine
function initEngine() {
  const scene = new THREE.Scene()
  const camera = getCamera()
  
  const { WebGl } = useWebGl()
  function everyFrame(callback = () => {}) {
    callback()
    WebGl.render( scene, camera )
    requestAnimationFrame(() => everyFrame(callback))
  }

  return {scene, everyFrame}
}
```

Everything below this line is from the initial post. I've fixed some other issues and simplified the codepen down to the exact issue I want help with. So the text above this line is the actual issue, and below this line is just for the sake of keeping the record:

[image]

**Context**

Ultimately my goal is to make a plane in three.js that matches/overlaps an HTML element and sticks to it. But I don't expect anyone to do all that work for me. The only think I'm asking for right now is how to make the size and position of the plane be consistent across screen sizes. And in fact, we could probably limit this issue to just the size.

**Issue:** if the plane is 10px from the left on one screen size it should remain 10px from the left on all other screen sizes. Right now, instead of getting that I'm getting the plane jumping all over the place. Its not just a resize update issue, if you refresh the page every time you try to change the window size you will still see that the plane is in random places and at random sizes(as demonstrated in the gif). In the code I'm setting the size of the plane with the size of the html image. But even if I set the size statically, the plane still randomly changes size on different screen sizes.

**Regarding position:** In the code I'm basically telling the plane to move to the top left edge of the canvas, and then offset back to the position of the HTML element based on that elements position from the top right of the screen. Which works. But only for my fullscreen desktop view. When the window changes size suddenly the offset isn't accurate anymore. Why? Sometimes the plane even changes size.

**My expectation**

I expected the plane to be the same size regardless of screen size.

**My best guess**

The issue is not related to the way I'm offseting the position of the plane. I know this because you can disable all of that and you still get the plane moving around in size and position on different screen sizes.Since disabling all code related to position and size still doesn't get rid of the issue of the plane changing size I'm assuming the issue has to be related to the way I'm dealing with he camera. I'm using an orthographic camera though it should be noted that the same issue is also present when using the perspective camera.

If my guess is right the problem should be with this part of the code:

```
function windowDimensions() {
  const height = window.innerHeight
  const width = window.innerWidth
  const aspect = width / height;
  return { height, width, aspect}
}

function cameraDimensions(aspect, viewSize = 1000) {
  const caps = viewSize / 2
  const sides = aspect*viewSize / 2
  return { caps, sides }
}

function getCamera() {
  const { aspect } = windowDimensions()
  const { caps, sides } = cameraDimensions(aspect)

  //const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, aspect, 0.1, 1000 )
  const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    -sides, sides,
    caps, -caps,
    -1000, 1000
  )

  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    updateCamera(camera)
  })
  
  camera.position.z = 500;
  return camera
}

function updateCamera(camera) {
  const { aspect } = windowDimensions()
  const { caps, sides } = cameraDimensions(aspect)
  camera.left = -sides,
  camera.right = sides,
  camera.top = caps,
  camera.bottom = -caps,
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. Ill describe how I solved it here for any future visitors. The problem is this code right here.

```js
function cameraDimensions(aspect, viewSize = 1000) {
  const caps = viewSize / 2
  const sides = aspect*viewSize / 2
  return { caps, sides }
}

export function getCamera() {
  const { aspect } = windowDimensions()
  const { caps, sides } = cameraDimensions(aspect)

  //const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, aspect, 0.1, 1000 )
  const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    -sides, sides,
    caps, -caps,
    -1000, 1000
  )

  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    updateCamera(camera)
  })
  
  camera.position.z = 500;
  return camera
}
```

Or, more spesifically the way i was gettting top, bottom and sides for the OrthographicCamera in this function right here.

```js
function cameraDimensions(aspect, viewSize = 1000) {
  const caps = viewSize / 2
  const sides = aspect*viewSize / 2
  return { caps, sides }
}
```

This way of calculating the camera works fine if you want your geometry to scale up and down with the render. But for what I was trying to do, ironically, I needed to set the values using the window size. Like this:

```js
const cameraDimensions = (aspect, viewSize = 1000) => ({
  caps: window.innerHeight / 2,
  sides: window.innerWidth / 2
})
```

Big thanks to Darkmatter on the three.js discord that made a codepen for me to dig through to find the solution. Heres his [codepen](https://codepen.io/alexpineda/pen/WNJOYgZ?editors=1111)

[image]